# C++17 static and constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I'm using the clang that comes bundled with Xcode 9.3, and I'm trying to understand whether the following result is an intentional part of C++17 changes:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct Test {
    static const int TEN;
};
template<typename T> constexpr int Test<T>::TEN = 10;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << Test<int>::TEN << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with c++11 or c++14, this prints "10".
However, compiling this with c++17, this prints "0".

What's going on?

Comment: clang 6.0.0 and gcc 8.1 produce 10, clang 5.0.0 seems to produce 0 though: https://godbolt.org/g/KMLKSV

Comment: Part of me wants to say "static initialisation order interacting with template specialisation instantiation rules", but without actually knowing much about C++17's changes, my gut can't believe this is anything but a bug.

Comment: Thanks tkausl. What's confusing about the Apple Xcode clang version is it has it's own numbering scheme (`Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1`) -- Given your godbolt results, I guess it falls somewhere between clang 5 and 6.

Comment: You're not declaring `TEN` to be `constexpr`, but you're adding that on the definition?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are mixing const and constexpr. But I am not sure if this is exposing a bug in the compiler, or this is "no diagnostic required" scenario where you made a bug for which compiler is not required to tell you you are wrong.

Comment: No, I can't declare TEN to be constexpr. It's a compile time error to do that. Maybe my understanding of constexpr is wrong, but I understood it to be that it implies const, and contents are determinable at compile time, so I don't believe there's any logical problem with defining a const-declared static member with a constexpr?

Comment: `TEN` is a `static` member so you can declare it `constexpr`.

Comment: This is a reduced example, in actual code, I have a header file that declares a `static const DataType value[];` and have several hundred lines to define that value in a .cpp file. I can't declare static constexpr DataType value[] without giving it the value in the header file -- and I don't want hundreds of lines of data in a header file. But I did want constexpr in the cpp file to ensure compile-time determination of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this elsewhere, a clang developer acknowledged that this was a bug in clang-5 c++17 implementation, and that it is fixed in clang-6 onwards.

Thanks to tkausl for his initial comment that showed differing results in clang-6 and gcc, which led me to ask elsewhere.